# Regex URL найти только нужные ссылки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, url

"><a href="https://www.test.net/index.php"

"><a href="http://test.org/test.php?test=1"

как мне сделать регекс который будет парсить только ссылки где есть знак равно =

"><a href="(.*?)" этот парсит все, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
const re = /<a href="([^"]+=[^"]+)">/;

console.log('<a href="https://www.test.net/index.php">'.match(re));
console.log('<a href="http://test.org/test.php?test=1">'.match(re));
```